# On the website, my mouse cursor selects text from distant parts of the page

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image, when I move my mouse cursor down the page and move it left and right, it starts to select the links on the navbar. How can I prevent this?

Comment: you can use pointer-event on css... also you need to know the hegiht of your navbar... maybe it is long enogh

Comment: Do you mean when you _click and drag_ the mouse cursor at the bottom of the page, it starts to select and highlight the text on the top? It's an expected behavior of any web browser. That is, if a dragged area has no selectable content, it'll scan up the page to find selectable content. In your case, because you have no page content but the header nav, the nav items are getting selected and highlighted. You can try it on any website to see the behavior in action. As @AliSafaei noted above, you can add `pointer-events` CSS property, if you want the particular nav items unselectable.

Comment: Without your code, we can only guess how to help. `pointer-events` is probably not the correct answer here.